# prevent all $http request if a token is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

How could I prevent all $http request in angular if a token is not resolved.
the token is stored at login in localStorage

I'm looking for something like

```
app.config("$httpInterceptor", function(){
   var token = localStorage.getItem("token")
   if (token == null){
//prevent all $http calls (get, post, put whatever calls)
}
})
```

Comment: Create an $http wrapper/proxy and add your check there in your override of post, get, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept every request and cancell them if the token is not set

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.config(function($httpProvider) { 
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      var canceler = $q.defer();
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if(!window.localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                 config.timeout = canceler.promise; //cancelled                         
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reject request even before it starts

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
            return {
                'request': function(config) {
                    if(!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                        return $q.reject()
                    } else {
                        return config
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use apply the concept of an interceptor.

```
app.factory('httpCanceller', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {

        var canceler = $q.defer();
        var token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        config.timeout = canceler.promise;

        if (!token) {
            canceler.resolve();
        }

        return config;
    }
  }
}]);


app.config('$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpCanceller');
});
```